# Blog color highlighting availability for Toit language?

Tags: toit

I wanted to write a blog post about the Toit programming language and embed some code. I noticed in some of [your medium blog posts](https://blog.toit.io/become-an-iot-developer-in-15-minutes-7df26ad5c0e1) you do seem to have some sort of color highlighting. If that's your own language extension, which plugin is it? I need it for Wordpress. If it is not a custom one for Toit but you use another language, what's the closest you have found that works best?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For medium, we tried the different solutions proposed in this blog post: https://medium.com/pythoneers/9-different-ways-to-embedded-code-in-medium-9213cb4c0a2e

And to get something that readers could easily copy and paste directly from the post (with the clipboard icon in the top right corner), we used Carbon.

We chose different backgrounds for .toit and .yaml files, and for the highlights, we used **YAML** for yaml of course, and (if I remember well) **Auto** for .toit - there was no perfect solution for Toit's highlights, but we settled for one that would highlight "main" and "import".